# SkiaSharp Printing to Windows printer

Tags: skiasharp

Im using SkiaSharp to generate bitmaps that I then print on thermal printers and to pdf files.  I now need to print to windows printers but I don't want to use bitmaps.  It would be cool if SkiaSharp could draw directly to a printer page canvas.

Has anyone done this or anything like it?

Alternative is to generate a PDF or XPS and then print that.

(Documentation and blogs for SkiaSharp are basically non-existant so please don't chastise me for not looking elsewhere - which I have).